# Scenarios in which `EventBus.publish` is not safe to call

Tags: platform-event

Looking for a comprehensive list of scenario's in which calls to `EventBus.publish` is not "safe" or things you need to check before calling.

[Not things that would cause your events to not publish](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260227/what-causes-platform-events-to-fail-to-be-published-and-should-i-cater-for-faile), but which would cause the code calling `EventBus.publish` itself to fail.

For example, I *think* this call counts towards DML limit, which would be something you'd want to check before calling.

Also other context specific things... Like, can you call `EventBus.publish` from a trigger on a platform event (same or different event)?

Comment: Also would include any secondary limitations like publishing an event before a callout, running out of DML down the line due to publishing too many events, etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes platform events to fail to be published and should I cater for failed platform event creations?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260227/what-causes-platform-events-to-fail-to-be-published-and-should-i-cater-for-faile)

Comment: @identigral that answers the second part of it!

Still wondering if there are any context where you cannot call `EventBus.publish`?

Comment: The docs cover this: _If isSuccess() returns false, the event publish operation resulted in errors, which are returned in the Database.Error object. This method doesn’t throw an exception due to an unsuccessful publish operation_

Comment: "This method doesn’t throw an exception due to an unsuccessful publish operation": To me that doesn't indicate that it NEVER throws an exception, just not due to a failed record. What if you reach your DML call limit?  Can you publish from a PE trigger (same or different object)?

Comment: IOW, are there any contexts or scenerio's where it's not actually safe to call `publish`?  I will update the question to only ask this part

Comment: The limit on publish events is covered by the referenced answer. The DML limit is no longer an issue as of Winter 21 if you Publish Immedate(ly) ([release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_platform_events_publish_immediate_limit.htm))

Comment: Not sure where you are seeing that... I see that they added a specific limit check for that `Limits.getPublishImmediateDML()` which indicates to me that if you exceed it, the `publish` call will fail...

Comment: For Publish Immediate in Winter '21: _With this change, they aren't considered part of the transaction's DML operations_ + _They count against a new, separate publishing limit of 150 EventBus.publish() calls_  reads like DML limit will not be applied. They make a point of this by noting that Publish After Commit will still count against DML

Comment: same different from the point of view of the question... If exceeding 150 calls to `EventBus.Publish` can cause an exception to throw (uncatchable), then that's something that needs to be checked before making calls to `EventBus.Publish`. IOW, would be part of the answer to this question (I'm assuming there are probably other scenario's)

Comment: Just tested... Throws uncatchable `System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151`.